# Random walk uniformly hitting a compact set

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, geometric-group-theory, topological-groups, random-walks

Suppose $G$ is a locally compact compactly generated group. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure that is:

1. Adapted to $G$, i.e. there is no proper subgroup $H$ such that $\mu(H)=1$.
2. Symmetric, i.e. $\mu(A)=\mu(A^{-1})$.
3. compactly supported, and $1_G$ is in the support.
4. $\mu<<\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is Haar.

Let $K$ be a compact set with $\lambda(K)>0$. Let $\mu^{*n}$ be the $n$-fold convolution $\mu*...*\mu$.

> Do there exist $c>0$ and $n>0$ such that $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}\geq c>0$ on $K$?

In other words, do a $\mu$ random walk, when hitting $K$, after many steps, hits it (in a sense) uniformly?

Answer (score 4):

In the special case of a finitely generated group, you can easily find a counter-example. So, without any other assumption, the answer is no.

Take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mu=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{-1}+\delta_1)$. These satisfy your assumptions. Now, take $K=\{0,1\}$. For every $n$, either $\mu^{*n}$ is supported on even numbers or on odd numbers, so either $\mu^{*n}(1)=0$ or $\mu^{*n}(0)=0$.

EDIT: Now that you added aperiodicity, for finitely generated groups, the answer is yes if yo replace adaptedness by irreducibility. More precisely, you only have to assume that there is $n_0\geq 0$ such that $\mu^{*n_0}(e)>0$ and that the symmetric support of $\mu$ generates $G$. Indeed, let $K$ be a compact (i.e. finite set). For every $x\in K$, there exists $n_x$ such that $\mu^{*n_x}(x)>0$ and using aperiodicity, for $n\geq n_x+n_0$, $\mu^{*n}(x)>0$. Since $K$ is finite, you can take $n=\max (n_x+n_0,x\in K)$, so that for every $x\in K$, $\mu^{*n}(x)>0$.

The exact same proof works in the general case if the following holds: for every $x\in G$, there exists an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$, some positive $c_x$ and $n_x\geq 0$ such that $\frac{d\mu^{*n_x}}{d\lambda}\geq c_x>0$ on $U_x$.

Comment: Absolutely right. A simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ would satisfy the above. However, periodicity is in a sense non-natural, so let me please in retrospect also add to the assumptions that $1_G$ is in the support of $\mu$. Sorry for being inaccurate about the details. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, on finitely generated groups, I agree. The more intricate case is the non-discrete one. There are two things that I don't understand in your answer:


(1) Why would such $n_x$ and $c_x$ exist? note that even if $x\in supp(\mu^{n_x})$, this doesn't imply $\frac{d\mu^{n_x}}{d\lambda}(x)>c_x\geq 0$.


(2) Even if $\frac{d\mu^{n_x}}{d\lambda}(x)>c_x\geq 0$, how do you go from that to $K$?

Comment: No I know, I'm just saying that with this stronger irreducibility condition, you have the result. Now, for your question (2): assume that you have (1) and let $K$ be compact. For every $x$ in $K$, you have $U_x$, $c_x$ and $n_x$, which gives you an open cover of $K$. Take a finite sub-cover and take the minimum of the $c_x$ and the maximum of the $n_x$ for this sub-cover and you get the result on $K$.

Comment: Suppose $n$ is the maximal index and $c$ is the minimal lower bound, and take some $x$ with which you obtained the finite cover. Why would $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}(x)\geq c>0$? sure, you have it for $n_x$, but why do you have it for $n$? (assuming $n\neq n_x$)

Comment: Well, more precisely, using the same property for $x=1$, you get $n_1$ such that $\frac{d\mu^{*n_1}}{d\lambda}\geq c_1>0$, Then, by induction, you get, for $n\geq n_x+n_1$, $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}\geq (c_1\lambda(U_x))^{n-n_x-n_1+1}c_x$ on $U_x$. This proves that for large $n$, every $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}\geq c$ on every $U_x$, which is enough to conclude.

Comment: Now, you might think that requiring that $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}(x)\geq c_x$ is a lot, but this is a consequence of what you ask.
Actually, if closed balls are compact (which should be the case in non-pathological groups since you're requiring local compactness), the fact that $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}\geq c$ on open balls is a consequence of what you ask, so my assumption about $n_x$, $U_x$ and $c_x$ does not seem to much to ask for.

Comment: (First of all, thank you for this great conversation!)
When you say "balls", in what metric do you mean?
In $\mathbb{R}$ for example, if we let $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x)=1_{[-1,1]}(x) \cdot (1-x)^2$, and take the open ball $U=(-1,1)$, then it is not true that $\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}(x)\geq c>0$ on $U$. Of course, it's true for convolutional powers of $\mu$, is that what you meant? and if so, would you mind adding some details as to why this is true? (in the general locally compact groups, not this specific example)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. What I actually meant is the following. Assume that the conclusion you're asking for is true. Let $g\in G$ and let $K$ be the closure of a neighborhood $U$ of $g$. There is $n$ such that $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}\geq c >0$ on $K$, so in particular, $\frac{d\mu^{*n}}{d\lambda}\geq c >0$ on $U$. I'am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: (no prolem about the delay/confusion) But how do you prove the existence of such $U_x,n_x,c_x$?

Comment: I don't, I'm saying that
1) under this additional assumption, you should get a result,
2) this additional assumption seems reasonable, since it should be deduced from the conclusion you want to obtain.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is positive under the assumptions boldfaced below, which hold at least when 
$G$ is a complete connected Riemannian manifold (see the Remark at the end of this answer), so that the case of $G=\mathbb R^d$ is of course included. 
On the other hand, the simple counterexample given by M. Dus shows that without a connectedness condition the desired conclusion will fail to hold in general.

Since the measure $\mu$ is nonzero, the set $E:=\{x\in G\colon f(x)>t\}$ is of nonzero $\lambda$-measure for some real $t>0$, where $f:=\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}$. Also, $E=E^{-1}$, since $\mu$ is symmetric. Hence,
\begin{equation*}
 f^{*2}(x)=\int f(y^{-1}x)f(y)dy\ge t\int_E f(y^{-1}x)\,dy\ge t^2|E\cap(xE^{-1})|=t^2|E\cap(xE)|,
\end{equation*}
where $dy:=\lambda(dy)$, and $|\cdot|:=\lambda(\cdot)$. By the regularity of the measure $\lambda$, 
\begin{equation*}
 |C_E|>\tfrac12\,|C| 
\end{equation*}
for some compact set $C$, where $C_E:=C\cap E$. 
**Assuming that $G$ has a countable basis of neighborhoods of $1_G$**, 
it follows, by continuity, that 
\begin{equation*}
 |(xC)_E\cap C_E|>\tfrac12\,|C| \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
for all $x\in B$, where $B$ is 
some (without loss of generality, symmetric) neighborhood of $1_G$. So, 
\begin{equation}
 f^{*2}(x)\ge t^2|(xE)\cap E|\ge t^2|(xC)_E\cap C_E|>\tfrac{t^2}2\,|C|=:c_1>0 \tag{2}
\end{equation}
for all $x\in B$.

**Suppose next that for some symmetric neighborhood $\hat B$ of $1_G$ such that $\hat B\subseteq B$ and all natural $n\ge2$ we have** 
\begin{equation*}
 a_n:=\inf_{x\in \hat B^n}\,|(xB)\cap \hat B^{n-1}|>0.  \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
(If e.g. $G=\mathbb R^d$, $B$ is the ball centered at $0$ of "radius" $r>0$ with respect to (say) the $\ell_\infty^d$ norm, and $\hat B=\frac12\,B$, then $a_n=r^d$.) 
Define recursively $c_n:=c_{n-1}c_1 a_n$ for $n\ge2$, with $c_1$ as above.

It follows by induction that 
\begin{equation*}
 f^{*2n}\ge c_n>0
\end{equation*}
on $\hat B^n$. Indeed, for $n=1$ this follows by (2) and the condition $\hat B\subseteq B$. For $n\ge2$ and any $x\in \hat B^n$, 
by induction and (2), 
\begin{multline*}
 f^{*2n}(x)=\int f^{*2}(y^{-1}x)f^{*2(n-1)}(y)dy\ge c_{n-1}\int_{\hat B^{n-1}} f^{*2}(y^{-1}x)dy \\ 
 \ge c_{n-1}\int_{(xB)\cap \hat B^{n-1}} f^{*2}(y^{-1}x)dy
  \ge c_{n-1}c_1 a_n=c_n>0.    
\end{multline*} 
(For the penultimate inequality in the above display, we used the fact that for any $y\in xB$ we have $y^{-1}x\in B^{-1}=B$ and hence, by (2), $f^{*2}(y^{-1}x)\ge c_1$.) 
Thus, the desired result follows if we **finally assume that for any compact $K$ and any (or, equivalently, any symmetric) neighborhood $U$ of $1_G$ there is a natural $n$ such that** 
\begin{equation}
 U^n\supseteq K. \tag{4}
\end{equation}

---

**Remark.** Conditions (1), (3), and (4), used above, will hold when $G$ is metrizable with a metric $d$ satisfying the following "linear" connectedness condition: 
\begin{equation}
 \forall x,y\in G\ \forall t\in[0,1]\ \exists z\in G\quad d(x,z)=(1-t)d(x,y)\quad \& \quad d(z,y)=td(x,y). \tag{5}
\end{equation}
In particular, condition (5) holds when $G$ is a complete connected Riemannian manifold; see e.g. [wiki/Hopf--Rinow theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem) and [wiki/Riemannian_manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold).

Let us now verify that (5) implies (1), (3), and (4). This is obvious concerning (1), since $G$ is now a metric space and therefore has a countable basis of neighborhoods of $1_G$. Also, (5) implies 
\begin{equation}
 B_r^n=B_{nr} \tag{6}
\end{equation}
for all natural $n$ and all real $r>0$, where $B_r:=\{x\in G\colon d(x,1_G)\le r\}$, the $d$-ball of radius $r$ centered at $1_G$.

Take now any real $r>0$ and any compact $K$. Then $K\subseteq FB_r$ for some finite $F\subseteq G$. By (6), for each $x\in F$ there is some natural $n_x$ such that $x\in B_r^{n_x}$ and hence $xB_r\subseteq B_r^{n_x+1}$. So, $K\subseteq FB_r\subseteq B_r^n$ for $n:=1+\max_{x\in F}n_x$, which verifies (4).

It remains to verify (3). Without loss of generality, there we have $B=B_r$ for some real $r>0$. Take any natural $n\ge2$, then any $a\in(1/n,1)$, and let $\hat B:=B_{ar}$. It is enough to show that 
\begin{equation}
 a_n\ge|B_b|>0, \tag{7}
\end{equation}
where $b:=\frac r2\,(1-a)>0$. 
First here, if $|B_b|=0$ then $|K|=0$ for any compact $K$, which would contradict the condition that $G$ is compactly generated. So, we have the second inequality in (7). To verify the first inequality there, take any $x\in\hat B^n=B_{nar}$, so that $d(x,1_G)=nar_1$ for some $r_1\in[0,r]$. Let 
\begin{equation*}
 s:=nar_1-\tfrac{r_1}2\,(1+a)=(n-1)ar_1-\tfrac{r_1}2\,(1-a)\in[0,(n-1)ar_1]. 
\end{equation*}
By (5), there is some $z\in G$ such that 
\begin{equation*}
 d(z,1_G)=s,\quad d(x,z)=nar_1-s=\tfrac{r_1}2\,(1+a). 
\end{equation*}
For any $y\in zB_b$, we have $d(y,z)\le b$ and hence 
\begin{equation*}
 d(y,x)\le d(y,z)+d(z,x)\le b+\tfrac{r_1}2\,(1+a)\le b+\tfrac r2\,(1+a)=r, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
 d(y,1_G)\le d(y,z)+d(z,1_G)\le b+s\le b+(n-1)ar-\tfrac r2\,(1-a)=(n-1)ar, 
\end{equation*}
so that $y\in (xB_r)\cap B_{(n-1)ar}=(xB)\cap \hat B^{n-1}$. 
So, $zB_b\subseteq(xB)\cap \hat B^{n-1}$, whence $|(xB)\cap \hat B^{n-1}|\ge|B_b|$, for all $x\in\hat B^n$, 
which implies the first inequality in (7).

Thus, all the conditions (1), (3), and (4) are verified.

Comment: That's a nice construction, but can you provide details on why is $\displaystyle \int_{(x+B)\cap \frac{n-1}{2}B}g(x-y)dy\geq c_1a_n$ ? Maybe I'm missing something but it does not seem to follow from the above estimates (that hold for $x\in B$).

Comment: @M.Dus : I have added a detail explaining this inequality.

Comment: Nice! however, this heavily depends on the geometry of $\mathbb{R}^d$. I'm thinking how to choose $B$ in the general locally compact case.

Comment: @iPe : Why do you think this heavily depends on the geometry? I have now replaced the former ball $C$ by an appropriate compact set, which always exists. In the comment now appended at the end of my answer, it is explained that all we need are conditions (1), (3), (4), and it is also explained that for $B$ we can take a small enough symmetric neighborhood $B$ of $1_G$. Can you give a good example of a continuous locally compact group where some of the conditions (1), (3), (4) fail(s) to hold?

Comment: I have now rewritten the answer in general terms, for locally compact groups under apparently broad conditions.

Comment: Thanks you for this discussion! I don't know what you mean by a "good" example, but: locally compact compactly generated groups need not be in general first countable. For example, if $\Gamma$ is any compact group, let $G=\Gamma^{[0,1]}$ with the usual product topology. That is a counter example for (3). 
As for (4), the group generated by an open neighborhood of the identity is connected, hence any non-connected group will no satisfy (4). That is not to say your answer is not helpful, on the contrary, it is super helpful and a pleasure to read!

Comment: (Clarification: $G=\Gamma^{[0,1]}$ is an example of a compactly generated locally compact groups, that doesn't have a countable basis of neighborhoods at $1_G$.)

Comment: I have now added a remark showing that the desired conclusion will hold at least when $G$ is a complete connected Riemannian manifold. On the other hand, the simple counterexample given by M. Dus shows that without a connectedness condition the conclusion will fail to hold in general.

Comment: Thanks! this is truly great, and I'm learning a lot from you, not to mention the fact that you put your time and effort to write down all the details. I appreciate it! I will just remark that with the added assumption that $1\in supp(\mu)$ (which is very reasonable, to avoid periodicity) , there still isn't a counter example.